# Let function $g:A\to A$, $\:\:\:g^{2016}=g\circ g\circ g...\circ g=id_A$ , Prove that $g$ is Inverse function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let function $g:A\to A$,  $\:\:\:g^{2016}=g\circ g\circ g...\circ g=id_A$ , Prove that $g$ is Inverse function

---

My attempted :

$g$ is Inverse function if it's Bijection

to prove $g$ is one-to-one function we need to show that $g$ is Left inverses :

we get that :$$g^{2015}(g(a))=id_A$$

so $g$ is one-to-one function

and to prove $g$ is Surjective  function we need to show that $g$ is right inverses :

we get that :$$g(g^{2015}(a))=id_A$$

so $g$ is Surjective function

$\implies$ $g$ is Bijection so it's Inverse function.

Is this answer is correct and enough to prove it , if not how to prove it the right way ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Your answer is correct and enough to prove it. In fact you don't need to prove that $g$ is bijective. It is enough to state that $g$ serves as inverse of $g^{2015}$.

Comment: Well done, notice that you immediately proved that $g^{2015}$ is the inverse of $g$.

Comment: I haven't upvoted many questions lately, but yours surely deserves it.

Comment: thanks a lot...